# Do custom PropType functions have to only return Error or undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm writing custom propType validation for React components. The [example in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes) show that the propType function should return an `Error` or nothing (`undefined` implicitly).

I'm running into a problem where we have adopted an ESLint configuration that we don't modify or inline disable where the example runs aground of the [`consistent-returns`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return) rule due to not explicitly returning something at the end. Adding a `return undefined;` at the end silences the linter (just plain `return;` does not), but that's not ideal. Does anyone know if returning anything else (like `null`) will cause unexpected behavior when React is interpreting the propType validations?

Comment: Linting should make your life easier not harder. Why not disable the rule in this case? If you already double checked the code and it's only a short utility method i don't see any issue with that.

Comment: I agree. However, the eng team has established and enforced hard-and-fast rules about not doing inline disabling (they have disabled inline rule disabling). So gotta find another way.

Comment: why not just use `return undefined`? It's functionally identical to both a plailn `return` and not having a return at all

Comment: I addressed that in my OP. Just `return;` gets flagged by the same linter rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can see from the `prop-types` package [source](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/checkPropTypes.js#L44) a type checker should return `null` or an `Error` object. In fact it even contains a warning that reminds you of only ever returning one of these.

So you can safely silence your linter warning by explicitly returning `null`.

Comment: Good find! I think that unequivocally answers the question. Would be nice if the example code showed that. I figured it the code was just a check for a falsey value but I didn't know where to look.